# Running MySQL queries in specific order

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if someone could advise me here. I have a page where I am updating information in a database, from the previous page I post any new images (with a caption too) and I have a checkbox for deleting images. On the processing page I have the following code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $dbhost = 'removed';
    $dbuser = 'removed';
    $dbpass = 'removed';
    $dbname = 'removed';

    function reArrayFiles($file_post) {
        $file_ary = array();
        $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
        $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);
        for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
            foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
                $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
            }
        }
        return $file_ary;
    }
    try {
        $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
    }

    $query="SELECT * FROM `soldier_info` WHERE `soldier_id` = " . $_POST['soldier_id'] ;
    foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row) {
        $soldier_pre_images = explode(",", $row['soldier_images']);
    }

    if($_POST['deletephoto']){
        $imagestodelete=$row['soldier_images'];
        $captionstodelete=$row['soldier_images_captions'];
        foreach($_POST['deletephoto'] as $todelete){
            $deleteexplode = explode("--",$todelete);
            echo $deleteexplode;
            $deleteexplodepath = $deleteexplode[0];
            $deletecaption=$deleteexplode[1];
            $imagesafterdelete= str_replace($deleteexplodepath.",","",$imagestodelete);
            echo $imagesafterdelete;
            $captionsafterdelete = str_replace($deletecaption."--","",$captionstodelete);
            echo $captionsafterdelete;
            $unlinkpath = str_replace('site url','..',$deleteexplodepath);
            unlink($unlinkpath);
        }

        try {
            $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
            $dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $q = $dbo->prepare("UPDATE `soldier_info` SET `soldier_images`= :image, `soldier_images_captions`= :captions WHERE `soldier_id`= :id");
            $q->execute(array(":image" => $imagesafterdelete, ":captions" => $captionsafterdelete, ":id" => $_POST['soldier_id']));
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            $db_error = "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        } 
    }

    if ($_FILES['photo']) {
        $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['photo']);
        $capcount = 0;
        foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
            $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $temp = explode(".", $file["name"]);
            $extension = end($temp);
            if ((($file["type"] == "image/gif")||($file["type"] == "image/jpeg")||($file["type"] == "image/jpg")||($file["type"] == "image/pjpeg")||($file["type"] == "image/x-png")||($file["type"] == "image/png"))&&($file["size"] < 9000000) && in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts)) {
                  if ($file["error"] > 0) {
                    $file_error = "Return Code: " . $file["error"] . "<br>";
                  } else {
                    $newfilename = "../assets/uploads/images/" . $_POST['soldier_id'] . "/" . $file["name"];
                    $file_fullname = "site urlv/assets/uploads/images/" . $_POST['soldier_id'] . "/" . $file["name"];
                    $new_caption = $_POST['image_captions'][$capcount];
                    if (file_exists($newfilename)) {
                      $file_exists = $file["name"] . " already exists. ";
                    } else {
                        if(is_dir("../assets/uploads/images/" . $_POST['soldier_id'])){
                            move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],$newfilename);
                            if (strlen($uploaded_images)>1){
                            $uploaded_images = $uploaded_images . ",". $file_fullname;
                            }else{
                            $uploaded_images = $file_fullname;
                            }
                            if (strlen($uploaded_captions)>1){
                            $uploaded_captions = $uploaded_captions . "--". $new_caption;
                            }else{
                            $uploaded_captions = $new_caption;
                            }
                        }else{
                            mkdir("../assets/uploads/images/" . $_POST['soldier_id'], 0777, true);      
                            move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],$newfilename);
                            if (strlen($uploaded_images)>1){
                            $uploaded_images = $uploaded_images . ",". $file_fullname;
                            }else{
                            $uploaded_images = $file_fullname;
                            }
                            if (strlen($uploaded_captions)>1){
                            $uploaded_captions = $uploaded_captions . "--". $new_caption;
                            }else{
                            $uploaded_captions = $new_caption;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (strlen($row['soldier_images'])>1){
                    $uploaded_images = $row['soldier_images'] . ",". $uploaded_images;
                    }else{
                    $uploaded_images = $uploaded_images;
                    }
                  }
                } else {
                  $file_invalid = "The file is not a jpg/gif/png file, or is larger than 20mb. Please try again.";
                }
                $capcount = $capcount+1;
        }
        try {
            $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
            $dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $q = $dbo->prepare("UPDATE `soldier_info` SET `soldier_images`= :image, `soldier_images_captions`= :captions  WHERE `soldier_id`= :id");
            $q->execute(array(":image" => $uploaded_images, ":captions" => $uploaded_captions, ":id" => $_POST['soldier_id']));
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            $db_error = "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }
    }

    $query="SELECT * FROM `soldier_info` WHERE `soldier_id` = " . $_POST['soldier_id'] ;
    foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row) {
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $surname = $row['surname'];
        $yearofbirth = $row['yearofbirth'];
        $dateofdeath = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['dateofdeath']));
        $ageatdeath = $row['ageatdeath'];
        $regiment = $row['regiment'];
        $battallion_brigade = $row['battallion_brigade'];
        $Coybty = $row['Coy/bty'];
        $rank = $row['rank'];
        $solider_number = $row['soldier_number'];
        $Next_of_Kin = $row['Next_of_Kin'];
        $CWGC = $row['CWGC'];
        $Place_Died = $row['Place_Died'];
        $Connection_to_Wymeswold = $row['Connection_to_Wymeswold'];
        $Cemetery = $row['Cemetery'];
        $LRoH = $row['LRoH'];
        $Grave = $row['Grave'];
        $Memorial = $row['Memorial'];
        $Pier_Face = $row['Pier_Face'];
        $Other_Mem = $row['Other_Mem'];
        $Other_Details = $row['Other_Details'];
        $soldier_images = explode(",", $row['soldier_images']);
        $soldier_images_captions = explode("--", $row['soldier_images_captions']);
    }
    $dbo = null;
    ?>
```

This isn't a live site right now and is in testing/dev. However the issue I am seeing is that, all the queries are running, but the page loads up as though the select has run first (by this I mean that the records returned are those from before the updates as processed. Can I force this select to run last so that it gets the latest records?

Comment: You mean which select to run last?

Comment: Please use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php  else http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @krzysiej I want to run this last: $query="SELECT * FROM `soldier_info` WHERE `soldier_id` = " . $_POST['soldier_id'] ;

Comment: Thanks @idstam I do intend to sanitize the input, as mentioned this is still in development, I wanted to get the functionality in first (possibly the wrong approach but its worked for me in the past

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the 'original' data on the last select because you are running the queries on different connections. Hence they will live in isolated transactions, that might not be properly committed when the last select runs.

If you run them all in the same PDO object I think it will work.

(If you take POST parameters and concatenate them into SQL your server will be hacked. It's just a matter of time and you have the URL here for everyone to see.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will go take a look now. I'm looking at the sanitizing today (once I get this execution order sorted)